# jQuery Sparklines click get element

Tags: jquery, sparklines

There are [docs for click events](http://omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline/#onclick) for jQuery Sparklines, but I can't find a way how I could find out which element was clicked.

So I display a list of items in a table and with a sparkline (their prices). When the user clicks a sparkline, I'd like to know which "item" he clicked. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a separate sparkline class for each chart you display. Then you have the possibility to define different functions for each chart.

```
    $('.clickdemo').sparkline();
    $('.clickdemo').bind('sparklineClick', function(ev) {
        var sparkline = ev.sparklines[0],
            region = sparkline.getCurrentRegionFields();
        alert("Clicked chart 1 on x="+region.x+" y="+region.y);
    });

    $('.clickdemo2').sparkline();
    $('.clickdemo2').bind('sparklineClick', function(ev) {
        var sparkline = ev.sparklines[0],
            region = sparkline.getCurrentRegionFields();
        alert("Clicked chart 2 on x="+region.x+" y="+region.y);
    });
```

I'm not sure if this was what you wanted to know. But this is my best guess :-)

Hope this helps.